# Downloaded .xlsx files not working with roo

Tags: ruby, roo-gem

In ruby while working with excel worksheets, i am using "roo" gem.
It is working well with the local files associated with my system.
But when i download a new excel file from internet and opening it with 'roo' throws error like

Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/roo-2.3.2/lib/roo/excelx.rb:364:in `block in extract_sheets_in_order': undefined method 'extract' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/roo-2.3.2/lib/roo/excelx.rb:358:in 'each'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/roo-2.3.2/lib/roo/excelx.rb:358:in 'each_with_index'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/roo-2.3.2/lib/roo/excelx.rb:358:in 'extract_sheets_in_order'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/roo-2.3.2/lib/roo/excelx.rb:400:in 'process_zipfile_entries'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/roo-2.3.2/lib/roo/excelx.rb:379:in 'process_zipfile'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/roo-2.3.2/lib/roo/excelx.rb:48:in 'initialize'
    from excel1.rb:5:in 'new'
    from excel1.rb:5:in '<main>`

roo version => 2.3.2
OS => Windows 7

Comment: You will need to be more specific about how to reproduce the issue. For example, is the problem with every Excel file you download or just the specific one you are downloading? Is the downloaded Excel file valid - ie can Excel open it?

Comment: Yes, for all the downloaded excel files which were opened immediately by using "roo", it throws the error..But if the downloaded file opened manually and saved without doing any change, then works fine with "roo"..

Comment: What are the names of the sheets in the excel-file? Do they contain special characters? Because roo is internally using a regular expression there.